# Configuration error in Apache

Tags: python, django, apache, windows-server-2008, mod-wsgi

When i created server In Apache 2.2 on Windows Server 2008, Python 3.3 and Django 1.5. It give me this error why?
This is in my conf:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / D:/Rocnikova_prace/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath D:/Rocnikova_prace/mysite

<Directory D:/Rocnikova_prace/mysite/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

[crit] [client 127.0.0.1] configuration error:  couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!: /hlavni_stranka/

Comment: Why do you have 'Require all granted' in the first place? Are you actually wanting to set up authentication? You are missing any directives to specify an authentication source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i Know where was the problem, It was in configuration:

```
<Directory D:/Rocnikova_prace/mysite/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Options FollowSymLinks
AuthType None
AllowOverride None
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

But it give me new error:

```
 [Sun Nov 10 13:07:13 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: D:/Rocnikova_prace/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
```

Why?

Comment: You don't need the AuthType directive and that should be 'Allow from all' and not 'Deny from all'. Deny is what causes it to be forbidden. Review what the Django documentation says to use.