# PHP code inside HTML when downgrading from PHP5.5 to PHP5.4

Tags: php, html, upgrade

After reinstalling Apache2 and PHP5 (from 5.5 to 5.4), when I look at my publishing Apache2 directory with the browser, I'm getting a strange output, as some of my projects, has some PHP code snippets inside the HTML. All of those projects worked before with PHP5.5.

The only thing that I've changed is `Require all granted`, which I had to comment it because it was throwing an error:

```
[crit] [client 127.0.0.1] configuration error:  couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!: /
```

Commenting `Require all granted` this problem is solved, but then, if I go to one of those projects, I get something like this:

```
...
<div class="articulo">
<article>
<div class="seccion gradient">
<section>
<header>
<h1>Welcome to BunchOfColors</h1>
<h2>Choose a color</h2>
</header>
25 ) $accuracy = 25; echo '
<div id="commonColors">
</section>
</div>
'; if( $newColor >= 0 && $newColor <= 0xFFFFFF ) { $myColor = (string) dechex($newColor); $myBackgroundValue = strtoupper('#' . str_repeat('0', 6 - strlen($myColor)) . $myColor); echo '
```

As you can see, there is some PHP code inside the HTML. 
The points where seem to do it are the `<` and `>` symbols, but I have no idea of why and how to solve it. This is the same part PHP code:

```
...
        <div class="articulo"><article>
            <div class="seccion gradient"><section>
                <header>
                    <h1>Welcome to BunchOfColors</h1>
                    <h2>Choose a color</h2>
                </header>
                <?php
                $newColor = 0;
                $accuracy = 0;
                $accuracy = isset( $_GET['accuracy'] ) ? abs( intval( $_GET['accuracy'] ) ) : 8;
                $newColor = isset( $_GET['newColor'] ) ? abs( intval( $_GET['newColor'], 0 ) ) : 0xFF8822; 

                if( $accuracy < 1 ) $accuracy = 1;
                if( $accuracy > 25 ) $accuracy = 25;

                echo '<div id="commonColors">'; 
                echo '<div class="commonColor" style="background: #5C4B51"><a href="' . htmlentities( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?newColor=0x5C4B51&accuracy=' . $accuracy . '#myColor' ) . '"> #5C4B51 </a></div>';
                echo '<div class="commonColor" style="background: #8CBEB2"><a href="' . htmlentities( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?newColor=0x8CBEB2&accuracy=' . $accuracy . '#myColor' ) . '"> #8CBEB2 </a></div>';
                echo '<div class="commonColor" style="background: #F2EBBF"><a href="' . htmlentities( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?newColor=0xF2EBBF&accuracy=' . $accuracy . '#myColor' ) . '"> #F2EBBF </a></div>';
                echo '<div class="commonColor" style="background: #F3B562"><a href="' . htmlentities( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?newColor=0xF3B562&accuracy=' . $accuracy . '#myColor' ) . '"> #F3B562 </a></div>';
                echo '<div class="commonColor" style="background: #F06060"><a href="' . htmlentities( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?newColor=0xF06060&accuracy=' . $accuracy . '#myColor' ) . '"> #F06060 </a></div>';
                echo '<div class="commonColor" style="background: #108F97"><a href="' . htmlentities( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?newColor=0x108F97&accuracy=' . $accuracy . '#myColor' ) . '"> #108F97 </a></div>';
                echo '<div class="commonColor" style="background: #FF8B6B"><a href="' . htmlentities( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?newColor=0xFF8B6B&accuracy=' . $accuracy . '#myColor' ) . '"> #FF8B6B </a></div>';
                echo '<div class="commonColor" style="background: #FFE39F"><a href="' . htmlentities( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?newColor=0xFFE39F&accuracy=' . $accuracy . '#myColor' ) . '"> #FFE39F </a></div>';
                echo '<div class="commonColor" style="background: #16866D"><a href="' . htmlentities( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?newColor=0x16866D&accuracy=' . $accuracy . '#myColor' ) . '"> #16866D </a></div>';
                echo '<div class="commonColor" style="background: #103636"><a href="' . htmlentities( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?newColor=0x103636&accuracy=' . $accuracy . '#myColor' ) . '"> #103636 </a></div>';
                echo '</div></section></div>';

                if( $newColor >= 0 && $newColor <= 0xFFFFFF )
                {
                    $myColor = (string) dechex($newColor);
                    $myBackgroundValue = strtoupper('#' . str_repeat('0', 6 - strlen($myColor)) . $myColor);
                    echo '<div id="myColor" style="background-color:' . $myBackgroundValue . '">' . $myBackgroundValue . '</div>';
                    $iniColor = $newColor;
                }
...
```

which worked perfect before.

Comment: you downgraded from php 5.5 to 5.4?

Comment: I think this has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889464/configuration-error-in-apache

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Not really. The main question is why the PHP code is shown in the HTML.

Comment: If you have PHP source code visible within the browser then Apache is not correctly serving the PHP (so it outputs PHP as plain text). Have you restarted Apache since making changes to the configuration?

Comment: @AlexP - Yes. I done it.

Comment: Are the h1 and h2 rendering correctly?

Comment: @Elin - Yes. They are.

Comment: It really looks like $accuracy >  is being interpreted as $>.

Comment: @Elin - After removing and installing again PHP5 and the same with `mysql-client` and `mysql-server`, the problem seems to be resolved. Thanks for your help.